# manipulate files with wildcard characters in filename

Tags: command-line

I just discovered that I can actually created a file named `*.txt` in Ubuntu.

Suppose I have `a.txt` `b.txt` and `*.txt` in my current directory.

How can I delete the third one using terminal? (`rm *.txt` will delete all)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to either escape or quote the wildcard:

```
rm '*.txt'
rm \*.txt
```

Answer (score 2):

Just use the ' on it. This wildcard(i don't know if it's really called this) makes sure that the shell reads it as string instead of a wildcard.Like:

```
rm '*.txt'
```

Answer (score 0):

In more complicated cases, sometimes the command line completion of `bash` or `zsh` can help:

With a file named `foo*.txt`, pressing the Tab key after the first two chars for completion:

```
$ mv fo<TAB>
```

could complete the file name including it's unusual characters - and automatically escape them as needed:

```
$ mv foo\*.txt
```

(Command line after pressing tab)